# Stop a moving box after 100px

Tags: actionscript

How can I stop this box from following the mouse after 100px on the left, then when I draw it back to the right over the 100px mark, make it continue to follow my box.

Code:

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, flyttBoks);
function flyttBoks (e:MouseEvent) {
    if(boks_mc.x > 100) {
        boks_mc.x = mouseX;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want boks_mc's position to depend on mouseX you need to check for mouseX in your if statement, not the position of boks_mc.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, flyttBoks);
function flyttBoks (e:MouseEvent) {
    if(mouseX > 100) {
        boks_mc.x = mouseX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, flyttBoks);
function flyttBoks (e:MouseEvent) {
    if(boks_mc.x > 100) {
        boks_mc.x = 100;
    }
}
```